# How to use pypy as a kernel in CPython Jupyter in windows?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, pypy

I installed python using the [Anaconda installer](http://anaconda%20installer) and am happily using the version of Jupyter that comes with it.  I have also downloaded the [(32-bit) windows version of pypy](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/downloads/pypy2-v5.7.1-win32.zip) and that works fine from the command line.

How can I get CPython Jupyter to use pypy as a kernel when running my python code?

Comment: are you looking for something like this https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/56nnqe/pypy_with_cpython_35_running_jupyter_notebook_not/

Comment: @MattiLyra Sort of except I want it to be just the kernel which should be easier than what that person achieved.

Comment: looking through this list (https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels) it doesn't seem like anyone implemented that already, so you might have to put together your own `pypy` kernel in that case. http://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kernels.html

Comment: @MattiLyra That's interesting.

Comment: turned it into an answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Pypy doesn't need a different kernel, it can just use ipykernel.  It thus isn't listed separately in the list of Jupyter kernels.

You can use the same methods used for [installing kernels for different Python environments](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html) to install a kernel for pypy.  Eg,

```
pypy -m pip install ipykernel
pypy -m ipykernel install --user --name pypy --display-name "PyPy"
```

Or

```
pypy3 -m pip install ipykernel
pypy3 -m ipykernel install --user --name pypy3 --display-name "PyPy3"
```

The extra options are just there so that there are useful names for the kernels.

Note, however, that iPython 6 does not support Python 2.7, so if you aren't using PyPy3, you'd need to install iPython 5 in PyPy (I think it should still work with the most recent Jupyter, however).

Answer (score 0):

looking through this list (github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels) it doesn't seem like anyone implemented that already, so you might have to put together your own pypy kernel in that case. [jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kernels.html](http://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kernels.html)

Comment: PyPy doesn't need a different kernel; it can just use ipykernel, the same kernel used for CPython.